# How to validate gridview for emptiness through the custom validator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, customvalidator

How to validate the gridview for emptiness through the `custom validator` :

---

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="!!! "
                                        ControlToValidate="GridView1" ValidationGroup="Add_valid" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

---

```
  protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
  {

  }
```

Comment: emptiness means gridview doesnt have any row

Comment: yeah ,this what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this..

```
 protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
  {
if(yourGridViewId.Rows.Count<1)
args.IsValid=false;
  }
```